# compartir imagen en javasciprt con html2canvas

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente codigo, y quiero compartir una imagen via waths app o facebook, con javascript puro ya que estoy trabajando con yii2, con la variable anchor lo unico que puedo hacer es descargarlo pero me sale error al compartir alguna sugerencia

```
document.getElementById('share').onclick = function () {
    if (navigator.canShare) {
        const screenShotTarget = document.getElementById('ref-bancaria');

        html2canvas(screenShotTarget).then((canvas) => {
            const base64image = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            let anchor = document.createElement("a");
            anchor.setAttribute("href", base64image);
            anchor.setAttribute("download", "image.png");            
            let image = anchor.click();

            navigator.share(image)
                .then()
                .catch((error) => {
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'error',
                        title: 'Oops...',
                        text: error,
                    });
                });
        });
    } else {
        Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            title: 'Oops...',
            text: 'Tu navegador no es compatible para compartir.',
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: y que error sale?

Comment: Entra al catch y arroja esto NotAllowedError: Failed to execute 'share' on 'Navigator': Must be handling a user gesture to perform a share request. En el swal error